# Android Studio 3.6.3 - Camera error on taking a picture: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, image, camera, onactivityresult, enoent

Since I've updated **Android Studio to 3.6.3**, I'm unable to get a taken picure in the `onActivityResult()` function. I'm using a Samsung phone with **Android 8**, and the **Storage** and **Camera** permissions are set as allowed.

Here's my code:

```
   int CAMERA = 0;
   int GALLERY = 1;
   Uri imageURI;
   File file;

   public void openCamera() {
       Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
       file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.jpg");
       imageURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
       intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageURI);
       startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
   }


 // onActivityResult
 @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          Bitmap bmp;

           // • IMAGE FROM CAMERA
           if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
              try {
                  File f = file;
                  ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());
                  int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                  int angle = 0;
                  if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) { angle = 90;
                  } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) { angle = 180;
                  } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) { angle = 270; }

                  Matrix mat = new Matrix();
                  mat.postRotate(angle);

                  bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, null);
                  assert bmp != null;
                  bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), mat, true);
                  bmp = scaleBitmapToMaxSize(800, bmp);

                  myImgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

               // error
               } catch (IOException | OutOfMemoryError e) { Log.i("log-", "ERROR: " + e.getMessage()); }
     }
  }// ./ If RESULT_OK
}


// Scale image
public static Bitmap scaleBitmapToMaxSize(int maxSize, Bitmap bm) {
      int outWidth;
      int outHeight;
      int inWidth = bm.getWidth();
      int inHeight = bm.getHeight();
      if (inWidth > inHeight) {
         outWidth = maxSize;
         outHeight = (inHeight * maxSize) / inWidth;
      } else {
         outHeight = maxSize;
         outWidth = (inWidth * maxSize) / inHeight;
      }
      return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, outWidth, outHeight, false);
   }
```

**Manifest:**

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

After a take a picture, I get this error in the Logcat, and of course, no picture gets displayed in **myImgView**:

```
ERROR: /storage/emulated/0/image.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where are you requesting `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, including the runtime permission?

Comment: in a separate Application class, the Camera permission is allowed in the app Settings, as well as the write and read external storage

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution by using a single line of code, it seems it has to be temporary but so far it works on Android 10 devices to.

Just add this line inside the `<application` tag in the **Manifest.xml** file:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

This will allow the app to save pictures and videos in the Internal Storage - into a folder with the package name of your project.